# How to insert merged row as first column in verticle text format

Tags: tables

I am using the code below and the pdf output. I want `Tested on` as vertical text from `IEMOCAP to CREMA`. Also Trained on from  `IEMOCAP to CREMA` with alone below it. How to do that?
Please suggest something to make this table more professional like can I change something to the fonts and size?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{rotating, makecell}
\begin{document}


\begin{table*}[ht]
    \caption{Cross-Corpus performance of the proposed method on four datasets}
    \label{cross}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll cccc }
        
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{6}{c}{Trained On}\\
        &Dataset & IEMOCAP & EmoDB & RAVDESS & CREMA\\
        \midrule
        
        \multirow{7}{*}{\rothead{Tested On}}&IEMOCAP && &&\\
        &EmoDB & &&&  \\
        &RAVDESS & &&&  \\
        &CREMA   & &&& \\
        \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
        &Average & &&&  \\
        \bottomrule
        
        
        %\multicolumn{11}{l}{M:Male; F:Female}
    \end{tabular*}
    
\end{table*}    


\end{document}
```

The output is shown below:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should define length of rotated text, from table code is seems that `multirow` cells span only four text lines etc

Comment: How to do that here........... \multirow{7}{*}{\rothead{Tested On}}&IEMOCAP && &&\\.........I mean where to pass length. I want whole Tested on in single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your question is not entirely clear and also ask for opinion based suggestions ...
- In the first step I limited myself to correct code wo, that it will work properly:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twocolumn]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[ht]
    \caption{Cross-Corpus performance of the proposed method on four datasets}
    \label{cross}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Tested On}
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll cccc }
        \toprule
        &           &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{Trained On}          \\
        \cmidrule{3-6}
        &  Dataset  & IEMOCAP   & EmoDB & RAVDESS   & CREMA     \\
        \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}[1ex]{\rothead{Tested On}}
        & IEMOCAP   &           &       &           &           \\
        & EmoDB     &           &       &           &           \\
        & RAVDESS   &           &       &           &           \\
        & CREMA     &           &       &           &           \\
        \midrule
        & Average   &           &       &           &           \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- For further help you need to provide content for least on table body row. The best this one, where the cells contents are the longest.
- Usually help, if you read packages documentation or make yourself more familiar with writing of tables by reading some introductory text. For example [wiki: tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

Comment: Can "Tested on" be shifted right, sir, with a verticle line for merged row.

Comment: @NITIndia, no. Your table construction doesn't allow this.  Macro `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` push cells contents apart as much as is possible, so reconsider, if table width must be equal to `\textwidth`. Vertical lines doesn't work well with  `booktabs` rules (`toprule, ˙midrule` and `bottomrule`). Do you read given link? There is described how to draw vertical lines, so you can test this yourself. Meantime, please edit your question and add informations for which I asked you in my answer.

Comment: Could you please this question and help me, stack community says you can tag and ask, but I am unsure how to tag you there. Link is : 
     https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/684316/how-to-show-toc-only-once-per-section-while-using-line-by-line-feature-in-beamer