# How to show the section name only once in the TOC

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{animate}
\mode<presentation> {
    \usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usefonttheme{serif}    
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    
}
\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
    \begingroup
    \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{parent=structure}
    \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=white}
    \begin{itemize}[<alert@+->]
    }{
    \end{itemize}
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents 
    \end{frame}
    

    \begin{frame}
    \section{Introduction}  
    \frametitle{Introduction}
    
    \justifying
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \textbf{XX}\\
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{myitemize}
        \justifying
        \only<1->{\item x1} 
        \only<2->{\item x2} 
        \only<3->{\item x3}
    \end{myitemize}
\end{frame}


    \begin{frame}
    \centering
    \Huge
    \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{THANK YOU}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Here]

The section title "Introduction" is shown three times in the toc. How to only show it once?

Comment: I am worried that this is so tough to answer, or maybe I am not able to explain it properly. Can any one tag someone who can answer this question please.

Comment: Besede fact, that you code is a bit unusual, it works fine.  So, what is your problem? Frame title "Introduction" appear only on  third frame which is shown in three steps, as you require in your `itemize` list.

Comment: @Zarko Sir, my query is outlined slide should have the Introduction heading as once only. For every itemisation, it shows another heading there so in this way three introductions. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sectioning commands like `\section` always need to be used outside of the `frame` environment. Never put them inside of a frame.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{animate}
\mode<presentation> {
    \usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
%    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usefonttheme{serif}    
    \usecolortheme{beaver}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    
}
\newenvironment{myitemize}{%
    \begingroup
    \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{parent=structure}
    \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{itemize/enumerate body}{fg=white}
    \begin{itemize}[<alert@+->]
    }{
    \end{itemize}
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \tableofcontents 
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Introduction}  
    \begin{frame}

    \frametitle{Introduction}
    
    \justifying
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    \textbf{XX}\\
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{myitemize}
        \justifying
        \only<1->{\item x1} 
        \only<2->{\item x2} 
        \only<3->{\item x3}
    \end{myitemize}
\end{frame}


    \begin{frame}
    \centering
    \Huge
    \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{THANK YOU}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```